# Circle, circle + triangle, ... sequence of groups of colored shapes:

Tags: visual, sequence

Source: https://ravens-2-progressive-matrices-clinical-edition.netlify.app/

[image]

I can't seem to find a logical consistency for the answers. What is the correct answer?

Comment: I hate these kinds of questions myself—it could literally be anything. There are an infinite number of continuations of any sequence. These are really “guess what I (the problem creator) am thinking” questions. It’s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is

> Answer 2

Because

> Each step is made of 2 items: one old + one new. We have exactly one occurrence of previous step's new item, and a new item appears - its occurence increases with the step number

As a summary, if we except step 1  we have

> Step 2: 1 red circle    + 1 new item: triangle
>  Step 3: 1 triangle      + 2 new items: blue square
>  Step 4: 1 blue square   + 3 new items: stars
>  Step 5: 1 star          + 4 new items: purple square
>  Step 6: 1 purple square + 5 new items: blue circle

To follow completely this rule, I would have started with

> empty cell: 1 occurrence of previous item (does not exist) + 0 occurrence of new item (red circle)

Comment: I think the start is exactly right: 1 occurrence of previous item does not exist, so you only have 1 new item: the red circle. You start counting with 1.

Comment: @Lezzup the new items should occur 0 times for this first step, am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, you're right. Indeed, at step *n* you should get *n-1* new items. I was squint looking :)